# How to prevent UITableView interaction while UITextField is FirstResponder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

Is there a simple way to prevent user interaction while entering text in a UITextField (the textfield is in a cell of the tableView)?

I've already tried this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

with the result that the keyboard also stops showing up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thought that comes to mind is adding a transparent UIView overlay that would "mask" everything surrounding your cell, intercepting all the touch events.  I suppose it would have to be two overlays - one for above the cell and one for below.

Comment: i'm pretty sure this will work...but i was just wondering if there is a easy "just set one preference"-way for this ^^

Comment: There is no single setting for this. Any UI modality you want in your app needs to be custom coded. The only built-in classes that are UI modal are UIAlertView and UIActionSheet.